# Is it possible to change the image style of a bootstrap progress bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to change the style of a bootstrap progress bar, and place the current percentage value in it. Clicking the button allows the value (width) to change, but not the background or text value.

Here is the code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#progress-bar1").css("width", "50%");
    $("#progress-bar1").attr("aria-valuenow", "50%");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    $('#progress-bar1').css("width", "10%");
    $("#progress-bar1").attr("progress-bar-danger", "10");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
    50%
  </div>
</div>
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Update" />
```

Comment: `$(function(){})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready` so you have a document ready THREE times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the class `progress-bar-danger` and update the `text` to 10%:-

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    $('#progress-bar1')   
     .addClass('progress-bar-danger')  // change to red
     .css("width", "10%")              // change width to 10%
     .attr('aria-valuenow', 10)        // change value to 10
     .text('10%');                     // change text to 10%
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j31s9x0n/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can create a jQuery plugin to set the progress value.

```js
(function($) {
  $.progressArray = ['danger', 'warning', 'info', 'success'];
  $.fn.setProgress = function(percentVal) {
    percentVal = percentVal === 0 ? 0 : percentVal || parseInt(this.attr('aria-valuenow'), 10) || 0;
    percentVal = Math.min(100, Math.max(0, percentVal));
    var progressIndex = Math.ceil(percentVal / 25) - 1;
    return this.css('width', percentVal + '%')
      .attr('aria-valuenow', percentVal)
      .text(percentVal + '%')
      .removeClass($.progressArray.map(cls => 'progress-bar-' + cls).join(' '))
      .addClass('progress-bar-' + $.progressArray[progressIndex]);
  };
  $.fn.addProgress = function(percentVal) {
    return this.setProgress((parseInt(this.attr('aria-valuenow'), 10) || 0) + percentVal);
  };
  $.fn.setTooltipText = function(text) {
    return this.tooltip('hide').attr('data-original-title', text).tooltip('fixTitle');
  };
  $.fn.replaceTooltipText = function(regex, repl) {
    return this.setTooltipText(this.attr('data-original-title').replace(regex, repl));
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ placement : 'bottom' });
  var $progressBar = $("#progress-bar-1").setProgress();
  $('#btn-decr').on('click', function() {
    $progressBar.addProgress(-parseInt($('#progress-step').val(), 10));
  });
  $('#btn-incr').on('click', function() {
    $progressBar.addProgress(parseInt($('#progress-step').val(), 10));
  });
  $('#progress-step').on('keyup change', function() {
    var pattern = /\d+(\.\d+)?/g, replacement = $('#progress-step').val();
    $('#btn-decr').replaceTooltipText(pattern, replacement);
    $('#btn-incr').replaceTooltipText(pattern, replacement);
  });
});
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" id="progress-bar-1" role="progressbar"
             aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-2 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-decr"
              data-toggle="tooltip" title="Decrease Progress by 25%">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> %
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="progress-step"
             min="0" max="100" step="10" data-buttons="true" value="25" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-2 text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-incr"
              data-toggle="tooltip" title="Increase Progress by 25%">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i> %
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to modify the "background-image" css property. In your HTML code, try adding the following, as an example:

```
<style>
    #progress-bar1{
        background-image: none;
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```